# Allowed to use a second if statement?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Am I allowed to do use a second "if" statement at the end of an existing if statement?

I am using "CODE A" to create conditional title tags for a WordPress website. Originally, "CODE A" did not include "CODE B", but I read that I could use "CODE B" by adding it towards the end of the existing if statement. Is "CODE A" correct?

Example of output of CODE A:
For category "Chicken" and website name "Recipes" and "page 3":

title displayed in browser:
Chicken - Recipes - page 3

.
**CODE A**

```
<title>
<?php
if (is_category()) {
    wp_title(''); echo ' - '; } 
elseif (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
    single_tag_title(); echo ' - '; } 
elseif (is_archive()) {
    wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; } 
elseif (is_page()) {
    echo wp_title(''); echo ' - '; } 
elseif (is_search()) {
    echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; } 
elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
    wp_title(''); echo ' - '; } 
elseif (is_404()) {
    echo 'Not Found - '; } 
if (is_home()) { 
    bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); } 
else { 
    bloginfo('name'); } 
if ($paged>1) {
     echo ' - page '. $paged; }
?>
</title>
```

.
**CODE B: Instructions copied from a website:**

> Another suggestion, as I’m still tinkering with my titles is to add
>   the page number to the end of the title if it is an archive or
>   whatever that has multiple pages. This way you avoid any duplicate
>   titles (which apparently are not advisable for search engines).
>
> The code I used for this is very simple:
>
> ```
> if ($paged>1) {
>      echo '- page ', $paged;
> }
> ```
>
> I put the code right at the end after everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. Were you receiving some kind of error? The only thing you might want to remove is the "echo" in front of the third wp_title() call.

Comment: No error but as a newbie, it seemed incorrect to use a second if statement. Thanks for your help!